# Data size in ASCII

Tags: c, ascii

I am a little bit confused about determining the number of bytes in an ASCII encoded text. I can't understand how ASCII encoding works. Let's take for example `255`. In Hex it's value is `0xFF` and it's size is 1 Byte (`255: 1111 1111`). In ASCII encoding, 2 is `0x32` and 5 is `0x35` so if we want to write 255 it would be `255 = {0x32, 0x35, 0x35}` The size of each one of them is 1 Byte. That makes 3 Bytes in total? I mean if I want to write pure text like `char *buffer[]="Hello!";` Should I count the number of characters and suppose that this is the number of bytes in total ?

Comment: Naughy: 255 is not part of ASCII encoding.

Comment: Yes but if I want to write 255, It's 2, 2 and 5 ? Is it 3 byte sized ?

Comment: @zerocoldTUN: Insofar that "255" is a `char[4]` type, you have a point.

Comment: 'I can't understand how ASCII encoding works' well, you going to have real fun with Unicode, then:)

Comment: @MartinJames I am trying to implement a protocol of communication based on ASCII encoding. The thing is I really can't make a difference between sending letters and numbers as characters (0..9 a..z A..Z) and as hex coded values (0: 0x00 in Hex but it's 0x30 in ASCII etc ..)

Comment: @zerocoldTUN: That's why there are MIME types.

Comment: *if I want to write pure text like `char *buffer[]="Hello!";` Should I count the number of characters and suppose that this is the number of bytes in total ?* If you are using this syntax and you want to treat it as an ASCII string that you can manipulate with C string functions, then it's one more byte for the terminating null (`\0`). `"Hello!"` uses 7 bytes, not 6. But 6 is the actual number of characters, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yes, number of characters is the number of bytes. But note, that some characters are not printable. And the 0x0 character is very special, as it is used to terminate C-string.

Comment: One thing, on the `\0` thing, note that `0` is just as good here, `\0` is simply an explicit *octal* literal with value 0. I guess folk like to use the leading backslash as it looks like you're escaping something. But you're not - it's just zero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are kind of mixing up three different, non-related representations here.

- 11111111b or FFh is the pure binary presentation of the decimal number 255.
- ASCII is a very old 7-bit character table used for displaying strings, where each character code is 1 byte large.
- Splitting a raw number in different bytes, such as splitting 255 into 11b, 101b, 101b is called [binary-coded decimal (BCD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal).

If you wish to represent the number 255 as ASCII, it would be the string `"255"`, which in binary form would be `0x32 0x35 0x35 0x00`.

> That makes 3 Bytes in total?

Probably 4, since you'll want to null terminate the string too, or you can't use it with C standard library string handling functions such as `printf("%s", str)`.

> `char *buffer[]="Hello!";`

This line is incorrect, you need to settle for either a pointer to a string literal `char* buffer`, or an allocated character array `char buffer[]`. The code you have written is *an array of pointers* (of array size 1 item), which is not what you want here. The compiler should complain about this.

> Should I count the number of characters and suppose that this is the number of bytes in total ?

Assuming ASCII incoding, then indeed. `"Hello!"` will contain 7 bytes: 6 data + 1 null terminator. In case of string literals you can actually check this size with code:

```
printf("%zu", sizeof("Hello!")); // prints 7
```